# C++: Implementation of virtual destructor necessary when using inherited structs with only properties?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I know that I need to define a virtual destructor (best option even if my class is `final`).
In my case, I am using C-like structures (no functions, no defaults, just plain members) and use inheritance to compose a new structure. I then store a pointer to the base class in `std::unique_ptr` and let RAII do the rest.

I am now curious if there is a need to also explicitely add a virtual destructor to avoid memory problems.

An example might be:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    std::chrono::milliseconds duration = std::chrono::milliseconds{-1};
    int count = 0;
};

struct B {
    int mode = 0;
};

struct C : public A, public B {
    int foo = 1;
};

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> base = std::make_unique<C>();
   base.reset(); // I expect here that A,B and C are destructed properly

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your expectation is wrong. Only the `A` part of your object will be destructed. That's because all you really have is a pointer to an `A` object, and that object have no knowledge of any possible child-classes.

Comment: Now try a pointer to `B` and observe a crash.

Comment: Was expecting this...
How about trivial destructible structs?

Comment: I don't know if it's unspecified, undefined, or something else, but with the trivially destrucible structures `B` and `C`, your code will likely seem to work as expected. Unfortunately, in any "living" code that has to be worked on and maintained for perhaps many years, this is not an assumption that you could continue with. It's always better to always use good habits like virtual destructors, even in your own small toy projects, so you won't forget the good habits when you work on the larger projects.

Comment: You're gonna get crashes if the base class is at non-zero offset in the child class. If it's at zero offset and all member destructors are trivial, then it should be safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the class is polymorphic or whether it is trivial.

If `delete` is called on a pointer of different type (up to cv-qualification) than the most-derived type of the object it points to and the pointed-to-type doesn't have a virtual destructor, then the behavior is undefined.

One obvious reason for this rule is that the base class subobject might not be located at the same address as the most-derived object. So the compiler would have no way of knowing what the offset to pass to the deallocation function needs to be.

One could maybe argue that a standard-layout class with trivial destructor would not need to follow this rule if a pointer to the first base class subobject is used, but the standard doesn't make that exception and your class `C` isn't standard-layout anyway.

See [CWG issue 1259](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1259) closed as not-a-defect. The size-aware global deallocation functions mentioned in the issue were also introduced with C++14, which is another reason that using a base class pointer may cause you problems in practice, even if the destructor is trivial and the address without offset.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr` then this will work as the deleter of the `shared_ptr` is created when the first pointer is created and doesn't change when the pointer is copied between `shared_ptr` instances. This doesn't apply in `unique_ptr` which will use `std::default_delete<T>` where `T` is the type of the `unique_ptr` instance not the type originally constructed.

See https://godbolt.org/z/TjP6dbo9G for some examples of `unique_ptr` failing and `shared_ptr` working.

Comment: but you could provide `unique_ptr` with a deleter as template argument? But then you would get `std::unique_ptr<A, std::default_delete<C>>`, which has few use cases.

Comment: Yes, but if you're explicitly specifying the deleter you might as well just use `std::unique_ptr<C>` directly, neither would provide you with polymorphism

Comment: @Sebastian actually you can't use `default_delete<C>` as it can't be passed a `A*`: https://godbolt.org/z/h7dzn9rrW

Comment: I like this answer, since it is basically a good solution and only takes ~1KiB in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @moerker just because it works doesn't necessarily mean its a good idea, making sure polymorphic types have virtual base destructors is always a good idea to avoid you shooting yourself in the foot